# Redis Pub/Sub Issue

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I am currently using Redis version 2.6.12 and 2.4.5 for windows port version for some performance analysis. I have written a pub/sub application which I have a window service acting as a subscriber. and another windows form acting as Publisher.

I have noticed that after sending around 50++ consecutive messages from the publisher. The subscriber stops responding to new messages. There is no exception thrown from the publisher side.

Same behaviour occurred on both version of Redis.

Has anyone experienced this kind of weird behaviour?

This is the code from my windows form (publisher):

```
using (var redisPublisher = new RedisClient())
{
    var message = new LastTrainProcessedMessage(DateTime.Now, "TEST", SystemMonitorStatus.Normal, 10);
    label1.Text += (String.Format(@"Publishing '{0}' to '{1}'", message.ToString(), ChannelName)) + Environment.NewLine;                
    redisPublisher.PublishMessage(ChannelName, ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(message, typeof(LastTrainProcessedMessage)));
}
```

This is the code from my Subscriber:

```
using (_redisConsumer = new RedisClient("localhost"))            
    using (_subscription = _redisConsumer.CreateSubscription())
    {
        try
        {
             _subscription.OnSubscribe = channel => _logger.Info(string.Format("Subscribed to '{0}'", channel));
              _subscription.OnUnSubscribe = channel => _logger.Info(string.Format("UnSubscribed from '{0}'", channel));                    
              _subscription.OnMessage = (channel, msg) =>
              {
                  _logger.Info(string.Format("Received '{0}' from channel '{1}'", msg, channel));
                  var ltpm = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<LastTrainProcessedMessage>(msg);

                  //persist to redis and trigger SignalR call...
                  _smState.UpdateLastTrainProcessedState(ltpm.ReadingTimestamp, ltpm.Location, SystemMonitorStatus.Normal);
                  _smState.AddAlerts(ltpm.NumberOfAlerts);                      
              };                    
              _logger.Info(string.Format("Started Listening On '{0}'", _channelName));
              _subscription.SubscribeToChannels(_channelName); //blocking
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to open up a terminal with: redis-cli psubscribe "*" to see if your messages are still sent even when the subscriber hangs?

The issue seems definitely to be from inside the `onMessage` listener, remove the following lines:

```
_subscription.UnSubscribeFromChannels(_channelName);
_subscription.SubscribeToChannels(_channelName);
```

and it should work.

Comment: Hi there, I have tried running that command and I can still see the messages sent from the windows form. I have also added the code for pubsub. Please have a look when you get the chance. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Updated my answer I think I found the issue

Comment: I did that and i still get the same problem.Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ok, so it may be an issue with the windows port, did you tried the same code on the official version of Redis ?

Comment: I say talking about the official version https://github.com/antirez/redis I'm pretty sure your code will work there (just run it inside a VM and share the port 6379 with your host)